# How to detect if object is stationary OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to print a message when a detected objected has stopped moving for 5 seconds.

I can detect faces and whether motion occurs between frames. What method can I use to combine these and print a message when a face has been detected, but not motion, for 5 seconds?

I've been trying to use something similar to the `time.time()` method used that prints a message once per second when a face is detected, but I can't quite figure out the correct logic to check that the motion detection code hasn't triggered.

```
import cv2 as cv
import time

# Open Webcam
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

# Define ret and size as frame info from webcam
# ret, size = cap.read()

# Define rows, cols, and '_' as the return from size.shape
# rows, cols, _ = size.shape

# Print results
# print('Rows', rows)
# print('Cols', cols)

# Face Detection haar_cascade
haar_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('haar_face.xml')

# Check if the webcam is opened correctly
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

# Start Time
t1 = time.time()

# Do the following when webcam is open
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    ret, frame1 = cap.read()
    ret, frame2 = cap.read()
    
    frame = cv.resize(frame, None, fx=1, fy=1, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)

    # Divide Frame into Regions of Interest (ROI)
    ROI1 = frame[0:180, 0:320]
    ROI2 = frame[0:180, 320:640]
    ROI3 = frame[180:360, 0:320]
    ROI4 = frame[180:360, 320:640]

    # Detect faces in each ROI
    faces_rect1 = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(ROI1, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5)
    faces_rect2 = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(ROI2, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5)
    faces_rect3 = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(ROI3, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5)
    faces_rect4 = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(ROI4, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5)
    
    # Draw rectangles around detected faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces_rect1:
        cv.rectangle(ROI1, (x, y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), thickness=2)
        t2 = time.time()
        if (t2 - t1) > 1:
            print('I SEE YOU IN 1')
            t1 = time.time() # reset start time
    
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces_rect2:
        cv.rectangle(ROI2, (x, y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), thickness=2)
        t2 = time.time()
        if (t2 - t1) > 1:
            print('I SEE YOU IN 2')
            t1 = time.time() # reset start time
        
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces_rect3:
        cv.rectangle(ROI3, (x, y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), thickness=2)
        t2 = time.time()
        if (t2 - t1) > 1:
            print('I SEE YOU IN 3')
            t1 = time.time() # reset start time
        
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces_rect4:
        cv.rectangle(ROI4, (x, y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), thickness=2)
        t2 = time.time()
        if (t2 - t1) > 1:
            print('I SEE YOU IN 4')
            t1 = time.time() # reset start time
        
    # Show all video feeds
    cv.imshow('ROI1', ROI1)
    cv.imshow('ROI2', ROI2)
    cv.imshow('ROI3', ROI3)
    cv.imshow('ROI4', ROI4)

    # Detect Motion
    # Modify frames to detect contours
    diff = cv.absdiff(frame1, frame2)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(diff, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
    _, thresh = cv.threshold(blur, 20, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    dilated = cv.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)
    # Find contours
    contours, _ = cv.findContours(dilated, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Draw rectangles around detected contours
    for contour in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv.boundingRect(contour)
        if cv.contourArea(contour) < 1000:
            continue
        cv.rectangle(frame1, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), thickness=2)
        cv.putText(frame1, 'Status: {}'.format('Movement'), (10,20), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,255), thickness=3)
        
    # cv.drawContours(frame1, contours, -1, (0,255,0), thickness=2)

    # Show Motion Detected Feed
    cv.imshow('Motion Feed', frame1)
  
    # Press ESC to break
    c = cv.waitKey(1)
    if c == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: how about listing all pixel places same for 5 seconds ?

Comment: I think that may be a bit too restrictive. The motion detection only draws rectangles around contours of a large enough area, but is constantly detecting much smaller pixel changes. I would want to ignore these smaller motion changes and consider the image stationary if, essentially, no rectangles are being drawn in the 'Motion Feed'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I accomplished my goal:

```
# Draw rectangles around detected contours
    for contour in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv.boundingRect(contour)
        if cv.contourArea(contour) < 1000:
            continue
        cv.rectangle(frame1, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), thickness=2)
        cv.putText(frame1, 'Status: {}'.format('Movement'), (10,20), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,255), thickness=3)
        t3 = time.time()
```

In the motion detection code, I added `t3` to reset the timer used further on.

```
# Draw rectangles around detected faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces_rect1:
        cv.rectangle(ROI1, (x, y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), thickness=2)
        t2 = time.time()
        t4 = time.time()
        
        if msgcnt1 == []:
            print('I SEE YOU IN 1')
            msgcnt1.append('x')
        if (t4 - t3) > 5:
            print('No motion detected')
            t3 = time.time() # reset start time
```

the `t4` time starts when a face is detected. Since `t3` restarts whenever motion is detected, the detected face is considered stationary if `t4 - t3` reaches 5 and the message is printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Initialize a list to store the current centroids
centroids = []

# Loop over each detected bbox
for i, bbox in enumerate(bboxes):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox
    score = scores[i]

    # Calculate the centroid of the bbox
    centroid_x = (x1 + x2) / 2
    centroid_y = (y1 + y2) / 2
    centroids.append((centroid_x, centroid_y))

    # Check if the centroid is moving
    if prev_centroids is not None:
        dx = centroid_x - prev_centroids[i][0]
        dy = centroid_y - prev_centroids[i][1]
        distance = np.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)

        if distance > threshold:
            # The centroid is moving
            # (do something here, e.g. draw a green bounding box)
            pass
        else:
            # The centroid is stationary
            # (do something here, e.g. draw a red bounding box)
            pass
    else:
        # This is the first frame, so all centroids are stationary
        # (do something here, e.g. draw a red bounding box)
        pass

# Update the list of previous centroids
prev_centroids = centroids
```